# Laravel interpreting a string in route as parameter

Tags: php, laravel, routes

I tried googling, but I can't phrase the question right, it is simple.

I have these 2 routes:

```
Route::get('admin_firme/{id_firma}/filijale/{id_filijala}', 'FilijalaAdminController@show'); 
Route::get('admin_firme/{id_firma}/filijale/create', 'FilijalaAdminController@create')
```

They call different controller actions. The problem is in the second route which calls the create method. The part /filijale/create is being interpreted as the parameter of the first route, thus calling the wrong method. How can I correct this?

I tried naming the route and generating an url to it, but it still calls the wrong method.

Comment: Have you tried this by changing the order they were defined?

Comment: I tried it now, but it shows another error not related to this problem. I will try to correct it to see if it works, then I will accept after you post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's two things you can do. The first, and easiest, is to swap the order of them round so when checking matching routes it checks to see if it's create first, and if not anything else matches `id_filijala`.

The second thing you can do is use pattern matching for `id_filijala`, for example if it only contained numbers then you could use:

```
Route::get('admin_firme/{id_firma}/filijale/{id_filijala}', 'FilijalaAdminController@show')
    ->where('id_filijala', '[0-9]+');
```

You can use any regular expression in the where.

Answer (score 2):

Just take the bottom one up ...

```
Route::get('admin_firme/{id_firma}/filijale/create', 'FilijalaAdminController@create');
Route::get('admin_firme/{id_firma}/filijale/{id_filijala}', 'FilijalaAdminController@show');
```

should work.